Fixed field of pro-p-sylow subgroup absolute Galois group contains all the $p$th roots of unity
Let $p$ be a prime number. Suppose $k$ be a field of characteristic other than $p$ and let $G$ be the absolute Galois group of $k$ with $G_P$ as a pro-p-sylow subgroup. Let $k_p$ denotes the fixed field of $G_P$. I want to show that $k_p$ contains all the p-th roots of unity.
My try: If $k_p$ does not contain some $p$-th root of unity say $\omega_p$ then $k_p(\omega_p)$ is a degree at most $p-1$ extension of $k_p$. But as $G_P=Gal(k_{sep}| k_p)$ this is not true?
However I am not sure about the last statement. Any help would be appreciated

The pro-$p$-Sylow subgroup of $G_p$ is an inverse limit of finite $p$-groups. Hence every finite quotient of $G_p$ has order a power of $p$. Saying that $k_p$ does not contain one (and hence any) non-trivial root of unity $\omega_P$ is the same as saying that $G_p$ acts non-trivially on $k(\omega_p)$, which implies that the restriction map $G_p\to \text{Gal}(k(\omega_p)/k)$ is non-trivial. But then the image of $G_p$ inside $\text{Gal}(k(\omega_p)/k)$ has order a power of $p$. This is impossible though, because $\text{Gal}(k(\omega_p)/k)\subseteq C_{p-1}$.

Could you please explain what do you mean by the restriction map ?

If $L/k$ is Galois, there is a restriction map $G\to \text{Gal}(L/k)$ that is given by $\sigma\mapsto \sigma|_L$. This is well defined because $L/k$ is Galois, so the image via $\sigma$ of any element of $L$ lies in $L$. Since $k(\omega_p)/k$ is Galois, you get a restriction map $G\to \text{Gal}(k(\omega_p)/k)$, which you can pre-compose with the inclusion $G_p\hookrightarrow G$, obtaining what I called restriction map.
